# integrating reports in a netbeans platform application

Tags: reporting, netbeans-platform

I am looking for a way to integrate jasper reports in a netbeans platform application. I have googled this and there seem to be no direct answer, so am asking to be helped in this.

to be specific i use a MySql database and ireport designer to design my reports. I need to display the specific reports in a report viewer and display it in a top component.

please direct me on a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you want to display the end result (ie a pdf, word doc, excel spreedsheet) or do you want to display the report designer?

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry for my late reply. I want to display the end result. for example a pdf displayed within the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you should be using the [JRViewer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/view/JRViewer.html) component.

Have a look at this [Jasper Reports Swing tutorial](http://kristantohans.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/new-to-jasperreport-build-your-first-impressive-application-part-2/). The only difference is that instead of embedding your [JRViewer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/view/JRViewer.html) in a [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) you'll be embedding it in a [TopComponent](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-windows/org/openide/windows/TopComponent.html)

Comment: thanks alot Tim. just following the tutorial. this is what i was looking for all along.